# Are these variants of std::vector::push_back constant or linear?

Tags: c++, vector, big-o, push-back

We all know that `std::vector::push_back` has constant (amortized) complexity.
It is constant because we say that the amortization cost is negligible, doubling every time. With reallocation being linear complexity.

Let's change our `std::vector` interface a bit to force reallocation in different fun ways.

### Reallocate at every `push_back`

Is `push_back` still `O(1)` (amortized) if we reallocated on every `push_back`?

At every `push_back` we go through all the items in the vector
I guess the constant part would drop here and both `push_back` and reallocation are `O(N)`

### Reallocate only on odd numbered push_back

Is `push_back` still `O(1)` (amortized) if we reallocate on every other `push_back`?

Compared to the other variant, would `push_back` still be linear `O(N)`? Or can we still assume it's constant amortized?

Comment: That looks like homework questions. Are those homework questions?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do your homework yourself?

Comment: nope, just personal curiosity and refreshing big(O) notation

Comment: homework questions times are fortunately far away in the past

Comment: O(n/2) is O(n).

Comment: Yes, both cases still linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case, would `push_back` still be constant?

No. It's `O(realloc(n))`, which is `O(n)`.

> In this case, would `push_back` still be linear `O(N)`?

Yes. It's *best-case* performance is `O(1)`, it's worst case performance `O(realloc(n))`, which is `O(n)`. If you call `push_back` N times, you will call `realloc` N/2 times, each using `O(N)`, so on average we have `O(N*(N/2)/N) = O(N/2) = O(N)`.

Compare that to the double-the-size `push_back`, where on N `push_back`'s we will only call `realloc` `log(N)` times. See [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/why-is-push-back-in-c-vectors-constant-amortized) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation! 
could you just elaborate quickly on why: `N*log(N)/N = 1 + log(N)/N` ? Wouldn't it be: `log(N)` with the two `N` being taken out?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot and misread my own code as `(N+log(N))/N`.